# Unable to retrieve metadata for - Erro ao criar Controller

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, mvc

Criei um projeto web com MVC e entity framework 4.5, e banco de dados MYSQL.

adicionei as dlls **MySql.Data** **MySql.Data.Entity** e **MySql.web**

Fiz todas as configurações conforme imagens abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segui o passo a passo e meu Banco foi adicionado conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei minha entidade por nome Cliente. Segue código:

```
namespace MysqlConnectorMVC.Models
{
  public class Cliente
 {
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmarSenha { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Também criei minha classe de contexto:

```
namespace MysqlConnectorMVC.Data
{
  public class Context : DbContext
 {
    public Context()
        : base("name=restauranteEntities")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
  }
}
```

Minha String de conexão está abaixo:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MysqlConnectorMVC-20171012215253;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MysqlConnectorMVC-20171012215253.mdf" />
<add name="restauranteEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ClienteModel.csdl|res://*/ClienteModel.ssdl|res://*/ClienteModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=toor;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=restaurante&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Porém ao tentar criar meu Controller a partir da minha entidade e do meu contexto conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

recebo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Já procurei a solução para esse erro, até mesmo aqui no stack, porém não consegui resolver.**

Minha questão é:
Como resolver esse erro? o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: selecione seu edmx e clique em F4 e vá na propriedade Connection String e copie e cole para seu webconfig e veja se resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Cara sei que já faz tempo mas aqui eu tive o mesmo problema ai deixei a parte de "Data Context class" em branco e funcionou normalmente.
aqui um link de uma pessoa que fez a mesma coisa

https://forums.asp.net/t/2051386.aspx?Error+when+adding+View+Unable+to+retrieve+metadata+for+efEntity+Could+not+find+the+CLR+type+for+Model+